# How to use one-to-many and many-to-one annotations correctly?

Tags: java, jpa, crm

Good day,

I have started my first JPA project based on a CRM application and I have some difficulties with understanding the correct usage of ManyToOne and OneToMany annotations. For instance, let's say I have two classes; these will be Account and User classes:

```
public class Account {

@OneToMany
private Set<User> userList = new HashSet<User>();
```

and

```
public class User {

@ManyToOne
private Account account;
```

How do I correctly annotate the many-to-one and one-to-many relationships? I've tried reading the docs but still I could not retrieve a correct conclusion.

Thank for your attention

Comment: The annotations should be working as they are - you would create two unidirectional mappings. So the question is rather what do you want to do differently?

Comment: In my situation, the Account class can have multiple users and an user can have just one account. I want to indicate this relationship via JPA annotations and I am really confused on how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'canonical'  OneToMany mapping for your case, meaning meaning bidirectional, with the foreign key in the table of the many-side (the owning side) would in your case look like this:

```
public class Account {

@OneToMany(mappedBy="account")
private Set<User> userList = new HashSet<User>();
```

and

```
public class User {

@ManyToOne
private Account account;
```

The only difference to your existing code is the `mappedBy` attribute, to change two unidirectional relationships into a single, bidirectional relationship.

Comment: Cheers Kostja! That's the information I needed. This gave me some explanation on the declared relationships.